# Height of Bootstrap Tab container is sum of all tabs

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to apply **Bootstrap Tabs** feature on my page. But when the page loads, the height of the tab container `.tab-content` is greater than the first tab, the **height is sum of all tabs**. And produces blank space at the bottom.

However this blank space gets disppeared on clicking second tab.

What is the solution I can make to hide the blank space on load itself.

Demo : http://www.bootply.com/BL42m1AdBu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All your tabs have the class `active`:

```
<div id="container_1" class="tab-pane fade active in">
<div id="container_2" class="tab-pane fade active">
<div id="container_3" class="tab-pane fade active">
```

just remove this class on your last two tabs and it should work as intended.

```
<div id="container_1" class="tab-pane fade active in">
<div id="container_2" class="tab-pane fade">
<div id="container_3" class="tab-pane fade">
```